# ordered list (and IE)

Tags: html, internet-explorer

My list ordering appears fine in chrome and FF, but not in IE (all appear as 1's).
I'm not even sure where to begin regarding what's going on.
I spent a little time on a google search, but I'm still not sure where to begin (my keyword combinations didn't bring me what I'm looking for, but a question about formatting problems in IE did bring me to this site, so I thought I'd try; I like the related questions window above the text box).

If any thoughtful readers have tips, tricks, links, suggestions, solutions, I'm interested in why it happens and how to fix it.

Here's the link: http://www.technion.ac.il/~balazs/htms/tops1.3.htm

We're a small enough community to tell folks to look at it in FF or Chrome, BUT I'd rather learn how to do it right . . .

Thank you in advance for any feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a page doesn't render as I expect, the first thing that I do is run it through the [w3c markup validation service](http://validator.w3.org/).

The following page highlights a number of errors with your HTML:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.technion.ac.il%2F%7Ebalazs%2Fhtms%2Ftops1.3.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Fix those up and all should be rosy!

Comment: Wow - Yay - THANKS!

I started to clean it up - it's coming along nicely (It already goes to 2) . . . I appreciate the awesome answer!

ROSY, ROSY, ROSY

Comment: Now that I've "fixed" that specific page, I remember WHY I had the <li> tag inside the font specification, instead of outside where it "belongs" - I don't know how to control the font size and color of just the ordered list NUMBER. When I add the definitions to the style sheet, it changes the entire list entry. What commands will just change the font size and color of the number only (without changing the font size or color of the text)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `li` element for lists. Any other tags are not allowed and will not validate. You seems to be using some sort of WYSISYG program or CMS that's wrapping each `li` in a span that gives them a black font color and a slightly larger size.

```
<ol>
<span style="font-size: larger; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><li>Login and open the program</li></span>
    <ol type="a">
    <li>Sign the logbook (name and phone number)</li>
    ...
```

The reason why in Firefox and Chrome it works is because they're slightly more forgiving.

---

And will you now excuse me while I rinse the residue image of Comic Sans from my eyes?

Comment: Yes, certainly. Combined with my amateur coding, we have an amateur designer who LOVES comic sans. So, is the solution then to witch the order,
<o1>
<li><span . . .

I'll try it.