# Formatting ordered list for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, list

I have a list which is correctly displayed in the newest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but in IE versions 8, 9 and 10 there is a very big space between the number and text in `<div>`.

How can I repair this? `list-style-position` must be `inside`, because I need background image under number and text. Absolute positioning is not good solution, because the text can be long.

```
<style>
  ol {
    list-style-position: inside;
    background-color: silver;
    font-size: 180%;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  li {
    border: solid 1px;
  }
  div {
    font-size: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>

<ol>
      <li><div>aaa</div></li>
      <li><div>bbb</div></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: may be this link help you
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607883/ordered-list-and-ie

Answer (score 0):

write this in your body tag

```
           <!--[if IE]>
        <style>
              ol {
                list-style-position: inside;
                background-color: silver;
                font-size: 180%;
               margin-left:-0.5%;
              }
              li {
                border: solid 1px;
               position:relative;
              }
              div {
                font-size: 50%;
                display: inline-block;
                position:absolute;
                padding-top: 8%;
                padding-left: 12%;
              }


        </style>
           <![endif]-->
```

Comment: IE 10 doesn't support conditional comments.